# Will a WMS handle RPF image scale?

Tags: raster, wms

When serving RPF imagery (Raster Product Format) from a WMS, will the WMS handle which layer should be on top? For example, let's say I request layer X and layer Y in some bounding box, and layer X should be displayed at scale 1:10000 and layer Y should be displayed at scale 1:20000

I would expect that at scale 1:5000, layer X would show up since it is the higher resolution image (since it displays at the lower scale). Then I would expect at scale 1:15000, layer Y would show up. Is this typical WMS server behavior?

Comment: Which WMS server are you using? Having looked at the docs for Mapserver, I suspect it can cope with it, but I'm not expert.

Comment: More just a general question of the typical behavior. I didn't know if it was a client's responsibility to honor the min/max scale or if it is the server's job to only serve the imagery in the correct scale ranges.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is No ~ it is not typical behaviour for a server to know which scales to display map layers.

You will have to explicitly set up the server to honour any scales that you wish to have the map layers displayed at.  You will also have to set up the order of the layers.